# Net::SSH2 with Windows SSH agent

Tags: perl

I am currently working on a connection between Simpack, and a HPC cluster server. I have to use perl for the scripts that conenct the two services.
I am currently sending the commands to the server via SSH, but the keys need to be encrypted.
The Solution I am currently working towards is using Net:SSH2 (libssh2) and making it get the Key from the Windows SSH service.
The SSH service works great when using it in CMD, but in perl I get the following Error: failed connecting agent (-42 LIBSSH2_ERROR_AGENT_PROTOCOL) at .\sshtest.pl line 7.

I have no Idea what the problem is, and would greatly appreciate any help.
This code basically contains everything I need from the module:

````
use Net::SSH2;
 
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect('IP here')
    or $ssh2->die_with_error;
$ssh2->auth_agent('username here')
    or $ssh2->die_with_error;
my $chan = $ssh2->channel()
  or $ssh2->die_with_error;
$chan->exec('pwd')
  or $ssh2->die_with_error;
print while <$chan>;```
````

Comment: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11146496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for OpenSSH agent support on Windows was added in version 1.10.0 of libssh2. See [libssh2 release notes](https://www.libssh2.org/changes.html)

I noticed this error when using the C API with version 1.9.0 of the library and updating to the 1.10.0 version fixed the problem.